Testing for non-existence of a method in API
I am designing a fluent builder pattern API that branches and allows different options based on what has already been called.
For example: Build().Foo().Bar() is valid code, but Build().Baz().Bar() should not be. This means the option Bar() should exist in the API if called after Foo(), but should not exist if Baz() has been called.
Testing for the existence is easy, since the tests won't compile if I can't call Bar() after Foo(). However, I cant figure out how to approach testing the non-existence. That is, how do I test that Bar() indeed does not exist among the callable API after Baz() has been called?
For some context: I am creating a DI framework, and the builder pattern is used for building the binding infos in a similar way to Ninject, for example: Bind<X>().To<Y>().AsSingle().FromNew().

an interesting problem for TDD advocates

Why do you feel the need to test for "non-existence"?

@candied_orange The builder will be complex in order to provide user ergonomics. For example there will be the aiblity to skip options for implicit defaults, which causes a huge inheritance chain. There are options that are incompatible with each other. In my opinion tests exists both for verifying and validating. Testing for non-existent API is part my verification, since it was also a design decision (prohibit at compile-time rather than throw at runtime). However, after calculating the amount of tests required (5k in the optimistic scenario), I decided to bite the bullet and not do this.

"there will be the aiblity to skip options for implicit defaults, which causes a huge inheritance chain." My god why? If you have known good defaults just init with them and make them overwritable.

"There are options that are incompatible with each other" I linked this already but maybe you didn't read it. Check out the doAlternatives() bit.

@candied_orange The wizard pattern you linked there is very similar to what I have in mind, with the added requirement that some of the steps can be omitted to be filled with defaults later on based on state that was explicitly set. The reason for the inheritance chain is to allow for skipping steps while also not losing the "directional" nature of the pattern, i.e. if you take a step, that step determines which steps you can take next, while still being able to skip the steps. I will think about whether using inner classes makes things simpler, thank you for bringing that into my perspective.

Reflection is the obvious way to do this - have a look at the type of object returned by Build().Baz() and examine what methods are available on it.
I would however question if this is a worthwhile test or not - if somebody does add a Bar() method to that type, there's a fair chance they'll just say "ah ha, that test is obsolete, I'll delete it" rather than "oh, I shouldn't have added that method". This may be better enforced by code review than a test.

Thank you. I was hoping there would be an equivalent of static asserts from C++ somehow, but reflection makes perfect sense also. My reasoning for having these tests stems from the same exact scenario, but instead of someone thinking the tests are obsolete, I was hoping it would give the idea that the API should not allow for what they are trying to implement due to design decisions, especially if I write big bold comments above the test case to indicate why it exists, preferably with reference to API design docs.

The trouble is that "Baz().Bar() does not exist" is not the same as "a function which provides the same functionality as Foo().Bar() does not exist; if someone creates Baz().DefinitelyNotBarIPromise(), your test passes but the consumer of the API can still do whatever you're trying to prevent them from doing. If forbidding the existence of Bar() is purely ergonomics, that might be okay.

Good point. I suppose the only way to prevent that would be to do an AST search, which is not worth the effort. Instead I will rely on having all API reviewed and documented to make sure no duplicates happen and hope nothing slips through the cracks. Then it would be trivial to test for the permutations of all available API.


how do I test that Bar() indeed does not exist among the callable API after Baz() has been called?

With the type system. In a statically typed language you get this test for free.
Fluent builders, at least ones that can vary the methods you are allowed to  call, have a name. That name is internal Domain Specific Language (iDSL). It works by returning differing types on each link in the chain. Different types will offer different methods to call. Trying to call one that doesn’t exist for this latest type is a compiler error. No need for reflection. No need for unit tests. Compiling is your test. If your IDE has it, this will even work with code completion.
iDSLs are very powerful. But they are a fair bit of work to set up. Use them to solve frequently recurring problems to offset this work.

Trying to write a test for "this doesn't compile" can be awkward, though.

@user2357112 compiling is the test. Call a Foo() method on a type that doesn't have it and most compilers will explain the problem fairly plainly.

But trying to integrate that into an actual test suite instead of ad-hoc testing can be a real pain.

@candied_orange A compiler usually will tell you that something doesn't exist, if you expect it to. But we need to test the negation – if it doesn't exist, your test doesn't compile, so it also won't succeed. Here we want somewhat of a verification of the correct declaration of the types of each method, not so much the actual implementation.

@PaŭloEbermann there is no need to write a test for everything that doesn’t exist. Which is good since infinitely more things don’t exist than do. Build().Baz().Bar() doesn’t need an explicit test since it won’t compile. You forbid it when you don’t define it.

@user2357112 prefer a design that makes a mistake be a compile time error over one that makes it a run time error. Makes testing easy.

@candied_orange - no, but as described this is a test which doesn't compile unless a mistake it made (i.e. the method which shouldn't exist does exist). Which means that your automated tests are largely useless because you can't compile and run them under happy-day conditions.

@candied_orange The point here is that there can be a mistake in setting up the method types properly, and we like to catch this with some kind of "test" if it happens. The compiler only helps us for mistakes with using the methods, not for mistakes with defining their types.

@SimonGeard if you really do insist on testing that certain using code doesn’t compile, for whatever crazy reason, you absolutely can write a test that attempts to compile that code and will only pass when that compile fails. That is perfectly doable. It just seems like you’ll never run out of non existent code to cover.

@PaŭloEbermann So we should define what methods a type can’t have in a test suite rather than simply define what it can in the class. All because we don’t want the maintenance  programmer adding methods where they don’t belong because we know the future better now then they will know it then. I really hope I never end up maintaining this.

@candied_orange Well, that's true, but you're going to jump through a lot of hoops to ensure that non-compiling tests don't break your testbed, and that successfully-compiling ones do. Perhaps you could put a bunch of non-compiling code in a resource folder, and have a test which attempts to compile it?
Nah... I think we both agree that this is a horrible idea.

The correct way to test for this is to achieve 100% code and branch coverage with your functional tests.
Then you know there is no extra hidden untested method that shouldn't exist

For existence you get 100% code coverage when it compiles. You can't call Build().Baz().Bar() because the type Build().Baz() returns doesn't have a Bar(). The fact that Build().Foo().Bar() exists doesn't mean every type that isn't Build().Foo() should be tested to prove it doesn't have a Bar(). If it did that would make every type ridiculously coupled. You can't add or remove a method from a type without needing to update the tests for every type.

not sure what you are getting at here. If you have 100% coverage that shows that all methods have a test. You only write tests for actual working functionality, so ergo you dont have any Foo.Baz.Bar or any other unwanted methods

eg adding foo.baz.definitelynotbar brings your coverage below 100%

a test callBarAssumingFoo passes but doesn't give you 100% branch coverage for the not foo case

it sounds like you’re trying to move how a class is defined out of the class and into the testing harness.

no, that would be like using reflection or something. here we just test that there is no extra functionality

Wait, are you saying once you get to 100% code coverage then you can detect whenever someone adds a method because the coverage percentage will drop?

mm yes, but assume they add something that doesn't work, like this barWithoutFoo. either you have < 100% coverage, branch coverage or they figured out a way to make it work. Your "MustBe100Coverage" check prevents missed failing combinations of functionality

“prevents missing failing” I’m not sure I’m parsing those three negations correctly. I can’t tell if you’re saying this is good thing or a bad thing.

I'm not sure how i can make it clearer, obviously if you test everything, then you know there is nothing which has no tests. If you have 100% coverage a "failing combination of functionality" eg barWithoutFoo that you have "missed" ie failed to check for, can't exist. Regardless of whether its named in the way you expect or not.

having a 100% coverage test (ie build fails unless test coverage is 100%) in your build is better than infinite "make sure a method called X isnt present on class Y" tests

OK so you're argument is that when you achieve 100% code coverage that stops them from writing anything new. You don't see them just writing something new and adding whatever test for it they like. Am I following this correctly?

no, it seems like you are deliberately misunderstanding at this stage tbh.
